# Azure on demand web job does not receive correctly formatted json serialized string

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-webjobs, ondemand

I have an on demand web job with asp.net mvc site deployed in azure. The web job attempts to send email with sendgrid.

Users of my site fill a form, optionally attach a file and click send. Server side I collect all data serialize it to json using Newtonsoft.Json. Both my web app and web job use the same version of Newtonsoft.Json.

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net47" />
```

Then I post the serialized data to my webjob using arguments

```
  private static void TrySendEmail(Customer customer)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(ConfigurationManagerExtension.WebJobUrl,
                "POST",
                new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"email",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CreateCustomerEmail(customer)) }
                }));
        }
    }
```

The serialized data gets received by my webjob which attempts to deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json and send email using sendgrid

On running the web job in azure I get the error **Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: }. Path '', line 1, position 6.  at ABCD.Background.Program.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\ABCD\ABCD.Background\Program.cs:line 25**

Line 25 is

```
  DeserializedCustomer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedCustomer>(email);
```

Now I've tried in vain to attach debugger to this webjob since it is [on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905311/how-do-i-remote-debug-an-on-demand-web-job-deployed-with-a-web-app-in-azure-app)

Then I just copied over the web job function to a private function in my controller to check if the deserialization works in my web app. I ran my web app locally and surprisingly, *it works!!!*.

What could be the issue Newtonsoft.Json works in asp.net mvc app but not in on demand webjob deployed in azure?

Help

Update

Added logging to webjob using

```
  Console.WriteLine($"SerializedEmail - {serializedEmail}");
```

Resulting Trace

---

```
[08/28/2017 11:39:44 > 1a8d37: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[08/28/2017 11:39:44 > 1a8d37: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'ABCD.Backgr.exe' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: SYS INFO] Run script 'ABCD.Backgr.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: INFO] SerializedEmail - {email}
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: ERR ] 
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: }. Path '', line 1, position 6.
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: ERR ]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadUnquotedPropertyReportIfDone(Char currentChar, Int32 initialPosition)
[08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: ERR ]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseUnquotedProperty()
```

---

Update

Why is the post not being received correctly by on demand azure web job?

Update

Sent a simple object with webclient to azure webjob

```
  new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"email",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Email = "johndoe@se7ev.com"}) }
                }));
```

Log shows the same

```
    [08/28/2017 11:39:45 > 1a8d37: INFO] SerializedEmail - {email}
```

Is it the webclient or kudu scm?

Update

To receive the *email* parameter I do this but I receive nothing in my webjob

```
string serializedEmail = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serializedEmail))
        {
            serializedEmail = args[0];
        }
```

Still I do not receive the serializedEmail sent by asp.net mvc.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Given that `DeserializeObject` fails, all the code that follows it is irrelevant. It seems very likely that your JSON isn't actually being retrieved properly - you should log the value of `email` in your method before deserializing it. I suspect it's not what you expect it to be.

Comment: @JonSkeet Logged value of email in webjob and for sure it is not what I'm expecting. Is the problem how Kudu is receiving the post from webclient?

Comment: No idea - but you can now narrow your question down to that aspect, not JSON deserialization.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure I'll update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to pass the parameters to the triggered webjobs. You should follow below types.

```
https://{yourwebsitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjobsname}/run?arguments=yourarugment
```

Besides,if you use console application as the web job. The console application get the args will remove the quotes inside a JSON.

Like this. If you send this json to the webjobs args.

```
{"Name":"johndoe@se7ev.com"}
```

The received string is:

```
SerializedEmail - {Name:johndoe@se7ev.com}
```

So you should changed the converted string by using below codes.

```
  string para = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Customer { Name = "johndoe@se7ev.com" });

    string escapedString = para.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    string url = @"https://{yourwebappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjobsname}/run?arguments=" + escapedString;
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
    //you could find the user name and password in the webjobs property
    string logininforation = "${username}:{password}";
    byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(logininforation);
    string encode = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byt);

    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + encode);


   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse() ;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction. Your code worked almost flawlessly (only change being I did not have to escape the serialized string. One thing I must point out for others is that when creating the email object I was returning an object since JsonConvert.SerializeObject parameter was an object. When I updated the method to return a concrete type your code started to work flawlessly. Thank you so much.